# execute php script from window scheduler without showing cmd popup

Tags: php, windows, cmd, scheduler

I have a simple PHP script that checks the PDO SQL connection and the script does something after that.

The problem is when I run it as a scheduled task from windows schedule even from a batch file or directly by running from the scheduler with `php.exe -f "script file"`
the command prompt window appears and this is relay annoying.

Is it possible to disable the cmd popup when running the script from scheduler?

Comment: That computer with windows has iis or apache installed? One way to do that is scheduling something like " wget.exe -q "http : // localhost/script.php" ". But remember that wget isn't native on windows, you have to download it

Comment: @GabrielSouto wamp installation

Comment: Just in case, try add -q after or before -f, for quiet mode, according to php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: just read here : https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-run-a-scheduled-task-without-a-command-window-appearing/

Answer (score 5):

On Task Properties, in General Tab, there is a option called as "

> Security Options

On this options, choose the second option which is

> Run whether user is logged on or not

[image]

After saving, it will ask your admin credentials. Enter your credentials, then your scheduler will not show any cmd window.

Comment: Thank you very much. After trying a lot of other methods

Answer (score 0):

Try use wget with -q. I have a machine with Windows Server 2012 + Apache and a scheduled task for every 5 minutes and using wget it didn't show any command prompt window.

I downloaded wget from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: I don't want download wget.  is -q  working with regular cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a tricky thing. You can try to use the [task.exe](https://github.com/Microsoft/php-sdk-binary-tools/blob/master/bin/task.exe) tool from the PHP SDK under the default task scheduler. Another option were to use an alternative cron implementation, for example a UNIX like [nnCron](http://www.nncron.ru/).